# How to return an object similar to std::pair in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am coming from c++ and I am trying to create validator class for user inputs in text fields. 
My function needs to return a `bool` and a message (if `bool` is YES message is `NULL`). Is there in Objective-C something similar to [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) from C++ (  which contains pair of values)?

Comment: Just create your own class. ObjC does not have a generics facility so that sort of class wouldn't be too useful in the library.

Comment: Also: why don't you just use `std::pair`, after all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `std::pair` in Cocoa; you can create your own. However, a more idiomatic approach to the problem is similar to other methods that return errors, namely, passing a pointer to a pointer to an error, and returning `BOOL`:

```
-(BOOL) validateInput:(id)input error:(NSError**)errPtr {
    // Validate the input
    // If the input is valid, do not assign `errPtr`, and return `YES`
    // Otherwise, create a `NSError` object, and assign to errPtr
}
```

You can call this method as follows:

```
NSError *err;
if (![validator validateInput:@"some input" error:&err]) {
    // Show the error
}
```

For an example of how this idiom is used in Cocoa, see the `regularExpressionWithPattern:options:error:` method of the `NSRegularExpression` class.

Answer (score 7):

Well, not exactly a pair, but you have several options:

One. Use an array or a dictionary ("standard collection classes"):

```
NSArray *pair1 = @[@NO, @"Foo"];
NSArray *pair2 = @[@YES, [NSNull null]];
```

or

```
NSDictionary *pair = @{@"Flag" : @NO, @"Message" : @"Foo" };
```

so you get the idea...

Two: why not write your own Pair class if it doesn't yet exist?

```
@interface MyPair: NSObject

@property (assign) BOOL flag;
@property (strong) NSString *message;

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not try using Objective-C++? Just name your source file with a `.mm` extension and then you can mix c++ with objective-c. You can't mix classes but you can use the standard template stuff. So in some object Foo I have a method doFoo with this code:

```
std::pair<id, NSString*> foo;

foo.first = @"First";
foo.second = @"second";

NSLog(@"%@ %@", foo.first, foo.second);
```